# Nearest neighbor in R

Tags: r

I have two arrays "F1" and "F2":

```
F1 <- c(1,3,4,5)
F2 <- c(6,7,8,9)
```

I want to find nearest neighbor of each element in both "F1" and "F2".

Example: for value 3 in "F1", the nearest neighbor in "F1" is 4. And the nearest neighbor of 1 in "F2" is 6. And for value 9 in "F2", the nearest neighbor is 8, and 5 in "F1".

Comment: is the array always in ascending order?

Comment: "the nearest neighbor of 1 in "F2" is 6"  I did not understand this.

Comment: @Mamoun Benghezal, nearest neighbour is completely different from kmeans.

Comment: @Arun Raja, The arrays are random , not ascending

Comment: I want to find the nearest hit and nearest miss in Relief Algorithm. And my example showed that concepts. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the `RANN` package:

```
F1 <- c(1,3,4,5)
F2 <- c(6,7,8,9)
require(RANN)
nn2(F1,F2,k = 1)
```

which should produce the following results:

```
> nn2(F1,F2,k = 1)
$nn.idx
     [,1]
[1,]    4
[2,]    4
[3,]    4
[4,]    4

$nn.dists
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
[4,]    4
```

Naturally, you may consider modifying the `nn2` syntax to get more desirable results. The method uses the [ANN](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/) library which gives you a lot of opportunities on how to find your nearest neighbours.

I'm thinking that you may be actually interested in finding the *closest match*. For example to find the *closest match* for the number `6` you could do:

```
which(abs(F1-6)==min(abs(F1-6)))
```

This is not the same as identifying the nearest neighbours.

Comment: Thanks Konrad ! Can you tell me how to use it with array please. I am really doing in closest match.

Comment: @kgk try `sapply(F2,function(x) which.min(abs(x - F1)))`

Comment: Thanks Konrad ! You are so kind :)